# What is the difference between these adjectives: Ketoic vs. Ketotic

Tags: adjectives

From Wikitonary

> Ketoic: Relating to ketosis or ketoacidosis
>
> Ketotic: Of, pertaining to, or afflicted with ketosis

So, do you think these adjectives are synonymous, with ketotic being reserved to describe an individual that has ketosis?

e.g. He has nonketoic acidosis therefore the patient is nonketotic.

Comment: They seem to be different spellings with Ketotic being commoner and appearing in reliable dictionaries and Ketoic being absent or rare.

Comment: "ketoic" isn't in Lexico or Merriam-Webster, while "ketotic" is.

Comment: These seem close to being 'true' synonyms (doubtless because they're so rare in everyday conversation).

Comment: Google scholar has 29.2k hits for ketotic. Ketoic has 219, and suggests ketotic as the correct spelling.

Comment: Neither is likely to be found in common parlance. Medical Sciences.SE
 is surely the appropriate place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that, [as Ngram shows,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ketoic%2Cketotic&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) "ketotic" is far more popular.